# why is my SDE feature class not showing up in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class, arcgis-10.3

Just wondering if anyone has had a similar problem. We have a feature class on an SDE with about 1500 polygons. The attribute table says everything is there, but when we try to view it in arcmap, nothing shows up. If you run a function, clipping for example, it doesn't recognize any geometries from the feature class. We've tried running repair geometry, but that didn't work. Is it something to do with the extent?

Comment: What are the details of the spatial reference (coordinate system, xyzm resolution, tolerance and extents)? And what extent is reported for the feature class?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the RDBMS used for the enterprise geodatabase ("SDE" doesn't exist anymore), how the table was created, whether it has been registered with the geodatabase, and the RDBMS datatype of the registered rowid column.